# Including images in my Rmd generated html file disrupts the display of tables in my shiny app

Tags: html, r, shiny, r-markdown

When I include images in my html file, generated by knitting an Rmd file, it disrupts the behaviour of my shiny app. I've created a simple example below.

When the Rmd file **contains an image**, `includeHTML()` will display the html file, but not the table, whilst `includeMarkdown()` does not display anything.

When the Rmd **does not** include an image, `includeHTML()` will display the html file, but not the table, and `includeMarkdown()` will display the html file and the table correctly.

I suspect there is some conflict in the html, java of css, but I don't know how to work out what. Any help would be amazing!

I don’t particularly want to use an iframe.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Minimal Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'tabset',
        tabPanel("Tab1", 
                 checkboxInput("checkbox", "Show Image")
        )
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("conditionalPanel"),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$conditionalPanel <- renderUI({
    if(input$checkbox) {
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.checkbox == true",
          dataTableOutput("table")
        ),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.checkbox == true",
          # includeHTML("./www/README.html")
          includeMarkdown("./www/README.html")
        )
      )
    }
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      data.frame(
        Name = c("Anna", "Barbara", "Carlos", "David"),
        Value = c(23, 45, 12, 67)
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Shiny, `includeHTML` is intended to be used with a HTML *fragment*. That means a "piece" of HTML without `<html></html>` element, and without header. Otherwise, if this is a full HTML file, it disrupts the Shiny app. So you have to set `output: html_fragment` in the YAML header of your **README.Rmd** file:

````
---
output: html_fragment
---

*Here is a table:*

```{r cars, echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(summary(cars))
```

*Here is a plot:* 

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

Knit it and you get the HTML fragment **README.html**, that you can safely include with `includeHTML`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Minimal Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'tabset',
        tabPanel("Tab1", 
                 checkboxInput("checkbox", "Show Image")
        )
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("conditionalPanel"),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$conditionalPanel <- renderUI({
    if(input$checkbox) {
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.checkbox == true",
          DTOutput("table")
        ),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.checkbox == true",
          includeHTML("./README.html")
        )
      )
    }
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      data.frame(
        Name = c("Anna", "Barbara", "Carlos", "David"),
        Value = c(23, 45, 12, 67)
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]